# Como exibir o número do formulário em php

Tags: php

estou criando um pequeno sistema de comanda de lanchonete , e gostaria de saber como poderia fazer para que a cada novo formulário exibisse o número do atual  aonde está o nome comanda , assim não tenho que inputar o número e sim já vem automático EM PHP
FICO GRATO.
O código fonte

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Peixaria</title>
    <style>
        .add {
            text - decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.add,add2{ text-decoration:none;}
#selecionados input,#selecionados2 input{ margin:10px;}
</style>
    <h1>Peixaria</h1>
    <ul class="menu cf">
        <li><a href="secao.php">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="pedidos.php">Pedidos</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserva.php">Reserva</a></li>
        <li><a href="relatorio.php">Relatório</a></li>
    </ul>
    <main>
        <form>
            <header>
                <h2>Fazer Pedido</h2>
            </header>
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    <span>Comanda:</span>
                    <input type="text" value="">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Mesa:</span>
                    <input type="text" value="">
                </label>
                <span>Refeições/Bebidas/Sobremesas:</span>
                <div class="pedidos">

                    <select class="selecionar">
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
                        <option >Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option> 
                        <option  >Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</option>
                        <option >Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option>
                        <option >Caldeirada de Tucunaré</option> 
                        <option >Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Pirarucu</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Tambaqui</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Tucunaré</option>
                        <option >Tucunaré Frito</option> 
                        <option >Sardinha Frita</option>
                        <option >Jaraqui Frito</option>
                        <option >Pacu Frito</option> 
                        <option >Filé de Pirarucu Frito</option>
                        <option >Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</option>
                        <option >Guisado de Pirarucu</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                    <hr>
                    Selecionados
                    <hr>
                    <div class="selecionados">

                    </div>
                </div>
               <br>
                <div class="pedidos">

                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <select class="selecionar">
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Laranja 1l</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Laranja 2l</option> 
                        <option >Cola Cola 1l</option>
                        <option >Cola Cola 2l</option>
                        <option >Bare 2l</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Uva</option>
                        <option >Fanta Laranja</option>
                        <option >Sprit</option> 
                        <option >Cola Cola </option>
                        <option >Cola Cola zero </option>
                        <option >Guaraná Antarctica</option> 
                        <option >Guaraná Baré</option>
                        <option >Suco Goiaba</option> 
                        <option >Suco Manga</option>
                        <option >Suco Pessego</option>
                        <option >Suco Uva</option> 
                        <option >Suco Maracujá</option>
                        <option >Suco Laranja</option>
                        <option >Suco Caju</option> 
                        <option >Agua Mineral </option>
                        <option >Agua com Gas </option>
                        <option >Cerveja em Lata</option> 
                        <option >Limonada Natural</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                    <hr>
                    Selecionados
                    <hr>
                    <div class="selecionados">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </main>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(".add").on('click',function(){ 
            var cont=0;
            var holder = $(this).closest('.pedidos');
            holder.find(".selecionados input").each(function(){
                if($(this).val()==holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").html()){
                    cont++;
                }
            });
            if(cont>0) { 
                alert("Este item ja esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais..");
            } else{
                holder.find(".selecionados").append(
                    "<input disabled type='text' name='pedidos[]' value='" + 
                    holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").html() + 
                    "' ><input type='text' name='quantidade[]' placeholder='quantidade'><br>"
                );
            }
        });


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

a tabela 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se isso for registrado no banco de dados, você pode usar o id do último registro +1 para definir a próxima comanda.

Comment: A cada novo pedido é enviado para o banco de dados . E quando abro um novo pedido queria exibir o número do formulário aonde está escrito comanda , como poderia fazer isso em php . teria como colocar como resposta @JuniorNunes ?

Comment: Essa numeração da comanda é diária ou sempre incremental ao infinito?

Comment: é incremental ao infinito , tipo toda vez que eu abrir um pedido ela abre junto , como um controle mesmo , só que vai pro mysql. como poderia fazer para exibir la ?

Comment: Onde está o script que gera a comanda na base de dados quando se faz um novo pedido? Qual base de dados está sendo utilizada? Qual a estrutura da sua tabela? Essas informações não podemos adivinhar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pode usar o campo `id` da tua tabela de comanda para fazer o contador, tipo isso:

```sql
-- Retorna o último id.
SELECT c.id 
FROM comanda as c
ORDER BY c.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Ou se o ID estar exposto é um problema pra ti (pra mim seria), tu pode criar um campo `contador` na tua tabela (de preferência indexado):

```sql
-- Retorna o último contador.
SELECT c.contador
FROM comanda as c
ORDER BY c.contador DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

No PHP é só somar 1 ao resultado de uma das SQL anteriores que tu terá o próximo número.

**PS:** Vale lembrar que se dois usuários abrirem a tela ao mesmo tempo a "técnica do contador" pode repetir o número. Assim seria necessário outro mecanismo que garanta que cada contador seja único (exemplo: adicionar index `UNIQUE` no campo ou usar [contadores atômicos](https://redis.io/commands/incr) do [Redis](https://redis.io)).

**EDIT**:

Um exemplo de conexão com o banco de dados utilizando `mysqli` seria:

```php
// Conexão fictícia
$db_config = [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'user',
    'password' => 'my_password',
    'database' => 'my_database',
    'port' => 3306,
];

// Conecta com o BD
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_config['host'], $db_config['user'], $db_config['password'], $db_config['database'], $db_config['port']);

// Em caso de erro encerra o script
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}

$query = <<<SQL
    SELECT c.id as ultimo_id
    FROM comanda as c
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
SQL;

// Executa a query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);


// Se $result !== FALSE, não ocorreu erro com a query
// Se $result->num_rows !== 0, retornou pelo menos 1 registro do BD
if ($result && $result->num_rows) {
    /*
        Transforma o resultado da query em um objeto. Nesse caso seria o equivalente a:
        $resultado_da_query = (object) ['ultimo_id' => 1234]
    */
    $ultimo_id = $res->fetch_object()->ultimo_id
} else {
    echo "Erro ao executar query.";
    exit();
}

echo "A próxima comanda é $ultimo_id";
```

Comment: Muito bom, uma ideia para o contador, seria ele fazer a contagem novamente depois da submissão do formulário para poder salvar, e não usar o dado da view, já que poderia ser facilmente alterado!

Comment: Eu uso num sistema um contador mais complexo, mas no meu model eu tenho uma função `ultimo_codigo()`. Assim eu mostro qual é o **provável** código que o model terá e antes de salvar eu faço de novo para que o código seja realmente o último. Lembrando que esse campo é `UNIQUE`, assim eu garanto a integridade do DB

Comment: Como ficaria em php pra exibir na tela um echo ? @fernandosavio

Comment: Está usando algum framework?
É so executar a query acima e somar + 1 ao resultado. Como é um inteiro o `echo` funcionaria normalmente.

Comment: @fernandosavio não estou usando nenhum framework , como poderia fazer ?

Comment: Alterei a resposta e adicionei um exemplo usando `mysqli`.